# Restlet with GWT to call REST service with HTTP DIGEST

Tags: gwt, restlet, http-digest

i m using GWT 2.2 and restlet-gwt-2.1m4.

i m trying to call a rest service that uses HTTP Digest.

So i used the tutorial on Restlet wiki :

http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/46-restlet/112-restlet.html

First thing is this does not compile :

```
ChallengeResponse challengeResponse = new ChallengeResponse(c1,
                                                            resource.getRequest(),
                                                            resource.getResponse(),
                                                            "login",
                                                            "secret".toCharArray());
```

So i changed it to

```
    // 2- Create the Challenge response used by the client to authenticate its requests.
    ChallengeResponse challengeResponse = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_DIGEST,
                                                                "login",
                                                                "secret");
```

My second problem, is that no request are sent.
I checked with  Firebug and there is nothing (no GET request).

It seems that resource.get(); isnt sending anything at all.

Any idea what i am missing ? Does the code in the tutorial actually work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure? the link seems to work fine on my side.